# Removing Broken Media Library Images Efficiently In Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have recently cloned a Wordpress website in which a lot of the images were no longer needed. I did this by not moving across the images that I didn't need (~500 images). I now am faced with the Wordpress media Library 404'ing those images.

[image]

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update and augment the references to all those images in the WP database itself. If they were all in their own directory then you could do a 'search and replace' using that directory as an indicator.